# How can I configure WSO2 API Manager, So that throttling level(Service Level) will be decided by admin?

Tags: api, wso2, throttling, wso2-esb

I'm using [WSO2 API Manager](http://wso2.com/products/api-manager/) for publishing APIs, creating and managing a developer community. I have come across a problem with handling throttling levels(Service Level). In WSO2 API Manager, developer decides the throttling level(Service Level) he wants. It could be Bronze, Gold, Silver, Unlimited. Could it be configured other way around. What I mean is admin can decide what level of throttling is available for a particular user. Obviously developer will not go for Bronze, Gold or Silver when he could get Unlimited throttling level.

How can I configure WSO2 API Manager, So that throttling level(Service Level) will be decided by admin?

## Update

I'm referring to the Application developers. As for now, application developer decides which throttling level he needs according to what's available. How to set different throttling levels to different application developers? Eventually admin will decide which application developer has which throttling level?

EX: Even thought an application developer subscribe to a higher throttling level such as unlimited admin can review and change it to lower throttling level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if you mean Application developer or API Developer (API Creator) when you use the  term developer. There is an option to control Tiers available for an Application Developer. Application Developers Sign-up in the Store, Create/Register Applications and then Subscribe to different APIs. It's at the time of subscribing, the effective tier for that subscription is selected. When creating the API , even you allow multiple tiers, you can specify what roles should be allowed what tiers. So even an API have Gold,Bronze and Unlimited tiers, if the Unlimited is only allowed for admin role, only those App Developers having the admin role will be able to create a subscription with Unlimited tier. This [doc](https://docs.wso2.org/display/AM160/Throttling+Tiers) explains more about this feature.

Comment: Using the Tier permission UI you can specify to which roles a particular Tier should be shown. Say that Gold Tier is only allowed for the role gold_role. When a developer without the gold_role selects this API, he won't see the Gold tier. If you want a particular developer to use Gold Tier, you have to assign gold_role to that developer.

Comment: If you need to have a review process before creating a subscription, you can trigger a Workflow when creating subscriptions. With this the admin can determine whether to allow or not allow creating the subscription under a particular Tier. But cannot change the initial selection developer has made. You can find more info on https://docs.wso2.org/display/AM160/Subscribing+an+Application+to+API